# Liquibase cannot find my entity classes to generate diff in spring project

Tags: spring, hibernate, database-migration, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Liquibase cannot find my entity classes(JPA annotated) inside given package to generate diff.

when I use `mvn liquibase:diff` command It says  **No changes found, nothing to do** but my entities have new fields

I use spring framweork, JPA(hibernate), Liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

and here are my codes:

liquibase.properties

```
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:model.entity.persistent?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-changeLog.xml
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
username=username
password=password
driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-diff-changeLog-8.xml
```

pom.xml liquibase-hibernate config

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>


                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.6</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                    <version>1.19</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried with the following..

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <changeLogFile>changelogs/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.11</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                    <version>1.19</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

**liquibase.properties**

```
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:ch.karthi.liquibase.jpa.update.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
    referenceDefaultSchemaName=liquibasetest
    driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/liquibasetest
    username=USERNAME
    password=PASSWORD
    defaultSchemaName=liquibasetest
    changeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-changeLog.xml
    diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-diff-changeLog-8.xml
    outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-changeLog.xml
```

and it worked without any problem.

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building liquibase-jpa-update 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:diff (default-cli) @ liquibase-jpa-update ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
    [INFO]   File: liquibase.properties
    [INFO]   'outputChangeLogFile' in properties file is not being used by this task.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/liquibasetest

INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Reading hibernate configuration hibernate:spring:ch.karthi.liquibase.jpa.update.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Found package ch.karthi.liquibase.jpa.update.entities
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Using dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
[INFO] Performing Diff on database root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/liquibasetest (Default Schema: liquibasetest)
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Found table Customer
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Found table Customer
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Found table Customer
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Found primary key CustomerPK
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Found column id integer
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Found column age integer
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Found column name varchar(255)
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase-hibernate: Found column sexString varchar(255)
INFO 05.01.18, 12:58: liquibase: src/main/resources/liquibase-diff-changeLog-8.xml exists, appending
[INFO] Differences written to Change Log File, src/main/resources/liquibase-diff-changeLog-8.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.328 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-05T12:58:37+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/85M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you getting the difference for new jpa entity ? I mean the is it creating the change-set for create table?